# Bold character in textarea

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

i have a textArea where i show some  errors happened during a file loading.
Now i will want customize my text area in this way:

[image]

I want to show a few character in bold, I saw that Label consent this,but can I also do this with a textarea?

Comment: to my knowledge you can not do this, was this component represents the regular textarea from HTML.  i guess you could use the ``RichTextArea``, which is used to edit HTML code.  Or if you need more control over the controls above the input get the chkeditor-wrapper from the addons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved using a RichTextArea whitout top and bottom toolbar

```
.no-toolbar-top .gwt-RichTextToolbar-top{ 
display: none;
}

.no-toolbar-bottom .gwt-RichTextToolbar-bottom{ 
display: none;
}
```

Then i added these styles at components:

```
RichTextArea myArea = new RichTextArea();
myArea.addStyleName("no-toolbar-top");
myArea.addStyleName("no-toolbar-bottom");
myArea.setValue("<p><small> Error <b> Row 1 Col 2 </b> error description </small></p>");
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this you have to use the `RichTextArea` component or create your own widget.

Btw: you can hide buttons from the toolbar: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/171171

Answer (score 2):

I agree to the earlier answers saying that `RichTextArea` is the right choice.

However, as an alternative to using CSS for hiding its toolbars, the following will make them disappear as well (Vaadin 7.7.6):

```
RichTextArea myArea = new RichTextArea();
myArea.setReadOnly(true);
```